# Forloop choices of RadioSelect in Django ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I have list of choices. I want to get value one by one choice in HTML

## forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = UserInfor
    fields = [ 'gender']
    widgets = {
        'gender': forms.RadioSelect(choices=GENDERS),
    }
    labels = {   
        'gender': "Gender",
    }
```

## view.py

```
def profile(request):
user_info = ProfileForm()
return render(request, 'pages/test.html', {'user_info': user_info)
```

## test.html

```
{% for choice in genders %}
     <label class="radio-inline" class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="???">{{ ??? }}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for g_value, g_label in user_info.fields.gender.choices %}
    <label class="radio-inline" class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="{{ g_value }}">{{ g_label }}</label>
{% endfor %}
```